# Use variables as parameter in imported function

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters, module

I'm pretty new to python, so this might have a really obvious and simple solution, but here it is:
I created a custom module, imported it into another script [script2], and want to use local variables defined in script2 as the parameters for a function from the imported module

Module:

```
def encrypt(inputstr, securitykey = 1, encryptionkey = 1, decryptionkey = 1): #default value of keys is 1

inputstr = str(inputstr)

[converts inputed string into number ids based on encryption key and security key; this is like a 80 line long process, so I won't show it here]

inputstr = int(inputstr)
inputstr = inputstr * decryptionkey * securitykey
inputstr = str(int(inputstr)) #<this is stupid, I know, but for some reason this was the only way it worked

return inputstr
```

script2:

```
from ModuleDirectory import encryption

msg = input("Enter your message: \n \n")
seckey = input("Enter security key: \n \n")
enckey = input("Enter enrcyption key: \n \n")
deckey = input("Enter decryption key: \n \n")

encrypted = encryption.encrypt(msg,seckey,enckey,deckey)
print(encrypted)
```

When I do this, I get a NameError. How do I tell Python that I want to use the variables defined in script2 as the parameters for the function I imported from the module? As I said, I'm pretty new to Python, so I could just be being an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

def function(String ...) here String is problem!! Please give normal String variable name but not String! You are sending a String called string! So you have to get that String with one another String!! But NOT the Capital String! You can not use that as a name!

Comment: Sorry, that was just me being stupid -- the names of the parameters in this post were just placeholders for the names of the parameters in my actual script. In my actual script, It's not called 'String'. I should have typed this better lol. Thanks tho!

Comment: Totaly ok! We all do do many mistakes that we do not believe :) do its normal! Did you find the problem?? Maybe you can share your actual code here maybe we can help!

Comment: Haha ya, I'm not sure why I even used palceholders in the first place lol. I will edit the code in a sec.

Comment: There we go! I edited it so that it's now the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

in python you don't have to specify String, just leave it as var1... and it will work.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: In python. When you define a function with def(). You don't have to specify the type. If you leave it with just def(var1,var2,...). It will work without saying string

Comment: oh I see what you mean. I should have clarified that the string (now changed to inputedstring) parameter was actually a parameter that was used in the function, not just me specifying the type of object.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you mean but you have to call the function with the variables inside the parameter to pass the actual variables to the function. So call the function at the end with the variables in the parameter.

example

```
encrypt(msg, seckey, enckey, deckey)
```

but not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: Ya I did that, but when I run the script, I get an error saying that msg is undefined, even though it was clearly defined earlier